# Programmatically Change Look of Outlook Appointments

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I am trying to programmatically change the look & feel of outlook appointments in the calendar, e.g., add an icon to each appointment or similar. Is there any way of doing this? I have looked through the documentation, but could not find anything. This question is of course independent of language and also pretty much of the version of Outlook (I am willing to go with any version anybody knows how to do this).

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot set a custom icon for an appointment. The best you can do is set a category to make appointment displayed in the color of that category.